# Devo evitar o acesso repetido ao mesmo método dentro de um loop?

Tags: c++, desempenho, otimização

Eu me preocupo com o desempenho final de um executável, ao mesmo tempo, não quero penalizar o programador com cuidados excessivos ou desnecessários no código.

No código abaixo, por exemplo, ele retornará o mesmo valor do método `getPosition` por 10000 vezes:

```
for (int i=0; i<10000 ; i++)
    std::cout << i + window.getPosition().x << endl;
```

Neste caso específico, eu sei que `window.getPosition().x` **sempre retornará o mesmo valor**.

Para evitar uma perda de desempenho, deveria eu alterar o código para, por exemplo:

```
const int x = window.getPosition().x;
for (int i=0; i<10000 ; i++)
    std::cout << i + x << endl;
```

Isso sempre envolve uma preocupação adicional do programador.

Ou há algum cache inteligente, onde eu não deveria me preocupar com isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível que tenha alguma otimização em código que seja garantido que não muda. Não é o caso. Então deve ser melhor fazer fora. Você sabe que retorna o mesmo valor, o compilador não. Estou partindo do princípio que não retorna uma constante e não faça praticamente mais nada, porque aí pode ser que o método pode ser otimizado para manter a expressão no lugar da chamada e como a expressão é conhecida como constante já na compilação e aí nem precisa fazer a segregação. Na verdade é possível que até o laço desapareça. Claro depende do compilador e como o método foi escrito.

Otimizações sempre dependem de de diversos fatores, como o compilador que está usando, a plataforma que será gerado, a versão do compilador, as configurações usadas, o contexto.

Se o método tiver efeitos colaterais que potencialmente trarão resultados diferentes a cada chamada, então fazer o cache de um resultado antes do laço pode impedir de pegar as alterações. Por outro lado pode ser que não queira pegar modificações, aí se colocar dentro pode não produzir o resultado esperado. Então onde colocar tem a ver com a semântica desejada mais que a otimização.

Note que não é só questão do resultado retornado. Se sempre der o mesmo resultado, mas fizer algo colateral no método chamar uma vez ou 10000 vezes dará resultado total diferente, mesmo que o resultado retornado seja diferente.

Programador existe para ter essas preocupações. Pelo menos os mais profissionais. Para os mais amadores pode importar pouco. A tendência é a inteligência artificial resolver casos simples no longuíssimo prazo, e esses programadores devem ficar sem trabalho.

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de tentar adivinhar, por que não dá uma olhada?

Compilando o seguinte código:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Window
{
    std::pair<int, int> pos;

    std::pair<int, int> getPosition() const
    {
        return pos;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Window window{{42, 314}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        std::cout << (i + window.getPosition().first) << std::endl;
}
```

Com Clang 6.0.0, com otimização nível 3:

```
main: # @main
  push r15
  push r14
  push rbx
  mov r15d, 42
.LBB0_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  mov edi, offset std::cout
  mov esi, r15d
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov r14, rax
  ; Continua...
```

Perceba que o valor `42` foi passado para o registrador `r15d` e, sempre que o laço imprime o valor do primeiro membro do par, ele é passado como argumento pro `std::cout.operator<<(int)` através do registrador `esi`, copiando direto de `r15d`.

Algo parecido é feito por GCC 8.1, com as mesmas flags:

```
main:
  push r12
  push rbp
  mov ebp, 42
  push rbx
  jmp .L7
  ; Continua...
.L7:
  mov esi, ebp
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov r12, rax
  ; Continua...
```

O valor do primeiro membro do par é guardado no registrador `ebp`, que é passado como parâmetro para `std::cout.operator<<(int)` pelo `esi` também.

Veja os dois resultados no [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/GLgACY).

Como Maniero disse, há vários fatores em jogo na hora do compilador otimizar seu código e, por isso, deve-se evitar adivinhar o que irá acontecer com o seu código. Isole o problema e compile localmente, para ver qual é o resultado. Depois, compile o projeto todo e veja qual é o resultado comparando com o código isolado. Por fim, e mais importante, rode um perfilamento (profiling), ou um benchmark, do código isolado e não isolado, depois faça sua otimização em código (se necessário!) e compare os resultados com novos perfilamentos (não estou nem considerando a arquitetura onde seu programa estará rodando, mas seria bom também). Só assim, você terá certeza de que suas otimizações manuais tiveram sucesso.

Na maior parte dos casos, otimização prematura (i.e. tentar adivinhar o comportamento da execução do seu programa e otimizar em cima disso) é nociva e pode piorar muito mais as otimizações que o compilador consegue fazer.

Sempre otimize pensando nos dados que seu programa processará e pouco na construção do código, comparando perfilamentos pra provar o sucesso das otimizações.

Comment: Fantástico! Estou descobrindo muita coisa que jamais imaginava. Muito obrigado pela dicas e pelo apoio!